# Buildfire: Redirect a page to another plugin deeplink url

Tags: buildfire

I like to redirect a page(e.g. login page) to another plugin using the deeplink url? Like for example during login, I want to redirect the user to the other page using the deeplink that is setup in the Control.

**Like:**

```js
window.location.replace('deeplink url')
```

I am using the buildfire navigateTo, but don't know how to get the pluginId and instanceId, since it is not provided in the marketplace or in the myplugins section, there is not way to get it manually.

**Here is my code:**

```js
buildfire.navigation.navigateTo({
pluginId: '',
instanceId: '',
title: 'Dashboard',
folderName: 'Dashboard',
});
```

How to get the pluginId or InstanceId of a certain plugin?
Is pluginId or instanceId is the license key of a custom plugin?
Do I need to use pluginInstance to set the plugin data and pass it to the navigateTo?

Comment: there is another question that is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932297/buildfire-is-it-possible-to-load-a-plugin-within-another-plugin/45948876#45948876 however, here is the docs for NavigateTo https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigateto-plugindata  deeplink is used to navigate into a plugin from outside the app

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks. Big help.